# Can I use iTextSharp to rename "different visualizations" of a field with the same name?

Tags: .net, itext

Can I use iTextSharp to rename "different visualizations" of a field?  There are multiple instances of a field on the PDF, all with the same name, but with different subscripts.  E.g., "subform1[0].somefield[2]" and "subform1[0].somefield[3]"  Can I use iTextSharp to rename this, or replace it with a new field with a different name?  I see a comment on a similar post that this requires "direct PDF object manipulation".  Does iTextSharp provide this via renameField or another function?  Thanks.

Comment: PDF does not interpret such indices as something special,  so fields with names "subform1[0].somefield[2]" and "subform1[0].somefield[3]" already *are* different fields and can separately be renamed. But such names often are used in the context of XFA (pure or hybrid) forms, and the XFA form definition might cause fields to represent the same value. Thus, you might want to drop the XFA form definition altogether.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still struggling to rename these fields.  I understand I can't change the hierarchy (e.g., "form1[0].#subform1[0].somefield[2]" to just "newfield"), but even though a renameField("form1[0].#subform1[0].somefield[2],"form1[0].#subform1[0].somefield[2]") returns true and examining the stamper.Acrofields.fields shows the new name

Comment: Sorry... I hit Enter before finishing.   After what seems to be a successful RenameField (return value of true and seeing the new name in debug of stamper.Acrofields.Fields, the old field names are still displayed in Adobe LiveCycle.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks @mkl for your help.

Comment: I think iText field renaming only works in AcroForm forms. In case of hybrid or pure XFA forms I doubt the XFA form field definitions actually are renamed. Considering the field names, though, you appear to be working with a hybrid or pure XFA form.